# Is it possible to move function types out of the signature and into the where clause?

Tags: rust

I have a particularly long method signature in Rust, which looks like this when formatted using the latest formatter (for those interested, this is using [Gotham](https://github.com/gotham-rs/gotham)):

```
pub fn extract_body<'a, T: 'a>(
    mut state: State,
) -> Box<Future<Item = (State, T), Error = (State, HandlerError)> + 'a>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
{
```

The signature is extremely long, and I'd prefer something like this:

```
pub fn extract_body<'a, T: 'a>(mut state: State) -> Box<F + 'a>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
    F: Future<Item = (State, T), Error = (State, HandlerError)>,
{
```

Note the use of `F` in order to format a little nicer. Unfortunately, this does not compile. Is there any way to achieve the same without introducing another generic type? I'm currently invoking using the syntax `extract_body::<Value>` and would like to avoid adjusting this (since it's just a stylistic thing).

Is is possible to use the `where` syntax in this way, or is it strictly based on the use of generics? I'm finding docs on this syntax quite scarce.

Comment: As far as your last question goes, I am 99.99% sure that this isn't valid use of `where`. But there might still be an answer to the first question (is there any way to achieve the same).

Comment: I suggest you to create a [MCVE] on the playground, to lower the bar for potential answers. Also, have you simply tried putting `F` in the list of generic symbols?

Comment: The issue with your code is, other than a missing generic symbol `F`, that `Box<F + 'a>` indicates that `F` is a trait while in your `where` clause you specify that it is a *type* belonging to the `Future<...>` trait.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I can't provide a "complete" example, because I don't know the correct syntax for what I'm trying to write :) that's the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `type` to simplify your return type:

```
pub type ReturnType<'a, T> = Box<Future<Item = (State, T), Error = (State, HandlerError)> + 'a>;

pub fn extract_body<'a, T: 'a>(mut state: State) -> ReturnType<'a, T>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
{
    // ...
}
```

`where` cannot be used in this case, it is useful to add constraints to generic type, for example when you do static dispatch.

Comment: The first suggestion raises a warning that `generic bounds are ignored in type aliases` which might be an issue; as for the second suggestion, it mistakes `F` for a trait, which it is not.

Comment: @ljedrz `Future` is not a trait? In this case, I will delete the second part of my answer. I removed the warning, BTW.

Comment: `Future` is, but `F: Future<...>` isn't - it's a type implementing `Future<...>`.

Comment: @ljedrz Oh, you mean that this code do static polymorphism instead of returning a boxed trait? But AFAIK because `Box` is variant, a boxed struct can be seen as a boxed trait by the compiler if the struct implements the trait.

Comment: The compiler expects `F` to be a trait based on the return type signature (`Box<F + 'a>` - a boxed trait), but in the `where` clause `F` is a generic type parameter; I'm not super savvy with this so I might be wrong, but that's the error the compiler complains about (among others, since it's not an MCVE).

Comment: @ljedrz That's the problem... the OP did not write a MCVE, so I could not test my code, and I have no time to do it myself right no. I delete the second part.

Comment: Nice, this definitely makes it cleaner. I guess I was just hoping that `where` could be used in general to make signatures a little cleaner - i.e. you might not always have generics but not only generics make things messy :)

Comment: @ljedrz: Writing `Box<F>` and pushing `+ 'a` into the `where` clause would make `F` concrete again. But that might not be what the OP wants, either.